# Idiorm query to get today's records

Tags: php, mysql, database, date-range, idiorm

I have been playing around with Idiorm and I couldn't make it get all of the records from the database for today and yesterday.
So, the MySQL queries are:

```
SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE DATE(`time_stamp`) = CURDATE()    # today
SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE DATE(`time_stamp`) = CURDATE() -1 # yesterday
```

If I understand correctly, it cannot be exactly reproduced for Idiorm, right?
I also have tried the following option, which strangely did not work (returns empty array):

```
$today = ORM::for_table('video')->
        where_lt('time_stamp', 'CURDATE()')->
        where_gte('time_stamp', 'CURDATE()-1')->find_many();
```

Can you please correct me on how it should be done?

Comment: and use where_raw, e.g. ->where_raw('added_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best for MySQL performance to avoid stuff that uses functions on column values. For example,

```
WHERE DATE(time_stamp) = CURDATE()   /* slow! */
```

completely defeats the use of an index to look up records by time_stamp. It causes a full-table scan, which works correctly but slowly.  What you want is an SQL expression that will generate an index range scan.  This does that, for all time_stamp values since midnight of today's date.

```
WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE()
```

If you want to find all the time_stamp values from yesterday, you need this SQL statement

```
WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND time_stamp <  CURDATE()
```

That is, you want all the time stamps in the range [yesterday midnight, today midnight), which range excludes today midnight.

I think your Idiorm code has the `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` expression wrong. `CURDATE() - 1` works in Oracle, but not in MySQL.

Comment: Hi Ollie!
Thank you, that is a really useful piece of advice for a db novice like me!  
But unfortunately, I was not able to solve my problem. The query is alright, I hink the problem is somewhere in Idiorm. That's what I did:  
    $events = ORM::for_table('video')->where_lt('time_stamp', 'CURDATE()')->where_gte('time_stamp', 'CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->find_many();

Comment: I don't know much about idiorm. But maybe you should try... `->where_raw('time_stamp >= CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY') ->where_raw('time_stamp < CURDATE()' )`